# POST API automation using selenium with JSON Header

Tags: java, rest, selenium

I want to automate REST API using selenium(java), is it possible ? if it have header and body part in json form

Comment: Do you mean from the browser with fetch? That seems like a bad idea. Why not make regular http requests?

Comment: You don't seed selenium to automated REST API

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use ApacheHttpClient for example lerned from https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/

For instance a method in ApacheHttpClientPost could be like that:

```
public static String post(String tokenMobile, String method, String version, String body) throws Exception{

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
        builder.setScheme("https").setHost(host).setPath(method)
                   .setParameter("", ""); //Params
        URI uri = builder.build();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);

        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(httpget.getURI()); //Header
        postRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        postRequest.addHeader("version", version);
        postRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+tokenMobile);

        StringEntity input = new StringEntity(body); //Body in json
        input.setContentType("application/json");
        postRequest.setEntity(input);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));
        String output;
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            outputs = stringBuilder.append(output).toString();
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return outputs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I willl try

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is a tool which is designed for automation of UI or e2e test cases. You can integrate the Selenium test case with API test cases but that is always a bad idea.

Try something like `Rest-Assured, Postman, HTTPClient` if you want to automate the API test cases.